# How to get a dictionary from a json file in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I got this code for implementing my needing:

```
import json

json_data = []
with open("trendingtopics.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

for category in json_data:
    print category
    for trendingtopic in category:
        print trendingtopic
```

And this is my json file:

```
{
    "General": ["EPN","Peña Nieto", "México","PresidenciaMX"],
    "Acciones politicas": ["Reforma Fiscal", "Reforma Energética"]
}
```

However I'm getting this printed:

```
Acciones politicas
A
c
c
i
o
n
e
s

p
o
l
i
t
i
c
a
s
General
G
e
n
e
r
a
l
```

I want to get a dictionary being Strings the keys and got a list as value. Then iterate over it. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Did you mean `for trendingtopic in json_data[category]:` in your inner loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

json_data is a dictionary. In your first loop, you're iterating over a list of the dictionary's keys:

```
for category in json_data:
```

*category* will contain key strings - General and Acciones politicas.

You need to replace this loop, which iterates over keys' letters:

```
for trendingtopic in category:
```

with the below, so that it iterates over the dictionary elements:

```
for trendingtopic in json_data[category]:
```

Comment: ALternatively, you could iterate like this: `for key, value in json_data.iteritems(): print key; for item in value: print item`

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the `.iteritems()` method of the dictionary which returns key/value pairs:

```
for category, trending in json_data.iteritems():
    print category
    for topic in trending:
        print topic
```

Comment: Does `iteritems` implies any higher or lower cost to the operation against simple loop?

Comment: I think `for ... in mydict:` (the 'simple loop') is equivalent to `for ... in mydict.iterkeys():`. When you use `iteritems()` I'd guess it's a tiny bit  faster because it pulls the key/value pair as a unit, rather than having to go back and lookup whatever value.  My motivation is just that it makes the code look a little better.

Comment: Great, what happens if my json gets not same structure, for example, somtimes values are lists, sometimes other dictionaries, etc

Comment: If `trending` above was a dictionary rather than a list, it would just print it's keys.  If that's what you want, great, but if you need to handle them differently, then you need different code for each.